# MySQL Performance comparison INSERT vs LOAD INFILE (innoDB)

Tags: php, mysql, insert, debian

I have a specific question not addressed in prior posts:

I need to insert tens of thousands of data rows a day, perhaps over 100,000. Supposedly, LOAD INFILE is faster than INSERT. However, I run an innoDB database with lots of cache on a 16 GB RAM server:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 7680M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 64M
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
```

The question is whether under these circumstances, the LOAD INFILE method is worth the greater effort, considering that I would have to first create the file to be loaded from other data. Does anybody have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: Since all you want is a performance comparation you can do it yourself. Implement both way and acid test it with real data in a test environment. After you make a lot os tests you can answer your question and gain a upvote!

Answer (score 0):

My own performance test shows that an insert of 50,000 lines only took 3.5 seconds! Since that was so fast, I decided against even testing the LOAD INFILE version. Thanks.